# I need help in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I want to print First semester's Subjects in First Semester & Second semester's Subjects in Second Semester and so on. See this pic
[cick in image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0BfM.png)

*Maybe there is some logic in views.py that Im not having on my mind rn.Can someone help me in this logic and how to render it in semester.html page*
*My code is here.*

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.base import ModelState

# Create your models here.
class Course(models.Model):
    faculty = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Semester(models.Model):
    sem = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    faculty = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return F"Semester {self.sem} at Faculty {self.faculty}"


class Subject(models.Model):
    faculty = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    sem = models.ForeignKey(Semester, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subject_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views import View
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, AuthenticationForm, UsernameField
from django import forms
from django.utils.translation import gettext, gettext_lazy as _
from .forms import CustomerRegistrationForm
from .models import Course, Semester, Subject

# Create your views here.

def home(request):
    return render(request, 'app/home.html')

def faculty(request):
    course = Course.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'app/faculty.html', {'course':course})

class SemesterView(View):
    def get(self, request,id):
        obj = Course.objects.get(id=id)
        print(obj)
        semobj = Semester.objects.filter(faculty=obj)
        print(semobj)
        subobj = Subject.objects.filter(faculty=obj)
        print(subobj)
        return render(request, 'app/semester.html', {'obj':obj, 'semobj':semobj, 'subobj':subobj})
```

**semester.html**

```
{% extends 'app/base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block semester %}
<div class="bsc-csit">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row" style="margin-top:90px; padding-top:20px;">
            {% for so in semobj %}
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="bsccsit-box">
                    <h3 style="color: black">{{so.sem}}</h3>
                    <ul>
                        {% for suo in subobj %}
                        <li><a href="">1.{{suo.subject_name}}</a></li>
                        {% endfor %}
                        
                    </ul>
                </div>  
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock semester %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing the following in your template:

```html
{% for subject in so.subject_set.all %}
    <li><a href="">{{ forloop.counter }}. {{subject.subject_name}}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

You can get all `Subject`'s from a specific semester via `subject_set.all`.

You can also use `{{ forloop.counter }}` to provide a enumerative number with the associated subject.

Comment: That should be                                                                                                                        {% for subject in so.subject_set.all %}
    <li><a href="">{{ forloop.counter }}. {{subject.subject_name}}</a></li>
{% endfor %}          Anyway You gave me hint..Thanks brother love you

Comment: Yes you're right, i've edited answer! No problem bud,